# Command line output as HTML to a Browser, watch for new changes and refresh the browser

Tags: browser

I have a ruby command line application that outputs results of sequential calculations based on commands entered on the the terminal. The command-line-application can also output results to an HTML file.

How can I make the browser detect changes to the HTML file and refresh itself to display the new changes from a ruby application?

In effect, when I run commands on the terminal, the output is formatted using HTML and written to an HTML file. The browser "watching" the HTML file refreshes to display the new HTML file upon detecting that the HTML file has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a Ruby problem. You want your browser to reload a page on change. I would look to a solution like http://livereload.com/.